# Package fontspec Error: The font "CharisSIL-R" cannot be found

Tags: fonts, xetex, packages, fontspec

I have a package, suppose *mydummypackage* . When I compile the package I get the following errors:

> Line 10: ! Package fontspec Error: The font "CharisSIL-R" cannot be found.

> Line 12: ! Package fontspec Error: The font "CharisSIL-R" cannot be found.

Head of my package sty file:
**mydummypackage.sty** ::::

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1994/06/01]
\ProvidesPackage{mydummypackage}[2023/02/02]
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\RequirePackage{polyglossia}
\RequirePackage{CharisSIL}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{bengali}
\newfontface\bdnhtranslitfont{CharisSIL-R.ttf}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\translitfont}{\bdnhtranslitfont}
\newfontface\bnipafont{CharisSIL-R.ttf}
\makeatletter
```

Head of my package tex file: **mydummypackage.tex** :::

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mydummypackage}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\com}[2]{\textcolor{blue}{\textbackslash\texttt{#1}}\texttt{#2}}
\begin{document}
```

I tried many ways like using the CharisSIL-R package before other packages, by changing the locations of different commands but not working and getting the same error message. Please help. Thank you.
**MikTex, Texmaker, XeLatex**

Comment: does it work with lualatex?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I just checked with Lualatex, it is giving exact same error. Moreover, my whole package is designed for Xelex, therefore, kindly give us solution on xetex. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `\newfontface\bdnhtranslitfont{CharisSIL-Regular.ttf}`, that is the name of the font on my system.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's working. Changed the name from CharisSIL-R.ttf to CharisSIL-Regular.ttf . Thanks a lot. If you want, you can post this comment as an answer, I will mark it as my answer.

Comment: Not an explanation of your problem, but note that a new version was released a few days ago: https://software.sil.org/charis/charis-sil-release-6-200/

Comment: Possibility: The hyphen in the path name is not an ordinary hyphen. I have seen this behavior outside of TeX, specifically with another SIL font. One file manager finds the path, another denies it. Possible solution: Manually re-name the directory, so that you are sure it has an ordinary hyphen.

Comment: did you fond a solution?

Comment: if build the document in linux,  try to use fc-list to check the avaliable fonts.